# trying to print ascii text in same line python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.7

Im trying to write a program that takes a letter as input and prints the corresponding letter in ascii art. I try to do a print() statement but it prints in seperate lines and not the same line which i want.

```
 letter_I = """
 ###
  #
  #
  #
 ###
"""

letter_o = """
 ###
#   #
#   #
#   #
 ###
"""



print(letter_I + letter_o)
```

I want the input to be

```
###       ###
 #       #   #
 #       #   #
 #       #   #
###       ###
```

But i get

```
 ###
  #
  #
  #
 ###


 ###
#   #
#   #
#   #
 ###
```

How do i get the preferred output, and is it possible to print it mirrored without messing up the letters?

Comment: It's more complex. It would require iteration and/or more sophisticated data structure than simple multi-line string.

Answer (score 1):

Use this function

```
def combineStr(str1, str2):
    l1 = str1.split('\n')
    l2 = str2.split('\n')
    for i in range(min(len(l1), len(l2))):
        print(l1[i]+'\t'+l2[i]);
```

So you can do this:

```
combineStr(letter_I, letter_o)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it manually by splitting each strings line by line, and printing each line followed by a fixed number of spaces.

```
letter_I = """
 ###
  #
  #
  #
 ###
"""

letter_o = """
 ###
#   #
#   #
#   #
 ###
"""

letter_I = letter_I.split("\n")
letter_o = letter_o.split("\n")

for i in range(len(letter_I)):
    print(letter_I[i].ljust(7), letter_o[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

In one hand you could use ANSI terminal escape sequences  (see for example: https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html), but in this usecase i think it would be rather painful. Instead try to write the text by "pixel" lines, so first print the upmost "pixels" from each character, and then jumpt to the next row. For this of course you need to know the whole text in advance.
On the other other side, of course there is a lib for that, look at https://github.com/pwaller/pyfiglet

Answer (score 0):

You have to split the letters into individual lines and print one line of all letters before printing the next line.

```
letters = [letter_I, letter_o]
for lines in zip(*map(str.splitlines, letters)):
    print(*(line.ljust(5) for line in lines))
```

Here, `map` applies the `splitlines` method to each letter and then `zip` arranges them in the right way. `ljust` makes all lines the same width before printing them. (Alternatively, you could just `print("\t".join(lines))` but that gives you less control of the spacing.)

Output:

```
 ###   ### 
  #   #   #
  #   #   #
  #   #   #
 ###   ###
```